# Unable to remove virtualbox using 'sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-6.0;'

Tags: apt, virtualbox

Since today morning, I am trying to remove VirtualBox from my machine but I am getting following errors. I tried disabling virtualization as well but still getting the same error.

[image]
[image]

Kindly help me remove this.

Comment: Find the installed virtualbox package using: `sudo dpkg -l | grep virtualbox`
Then remove it using: `sudo dpkg --purge <Package>`

Comment: Already tried this but getting the same error. It seems that the VBoxSVC or any Virtual Machine as stuck in between which does not go away even after a reboot.

Comment: Did you try to remove the virtual machines and virtual hard drives using: `sudo rm ~/"VirtualBox VMs" -Rf` and 
`sudo rm ~/.config/VirtualBox/ -Rf`? You also kill all processes related to VBox using `sudo pkill VBox*`, then try to remove it again

Comment: what is the result of this `sudo dpkg -l | grep virtualbox` command?

Comment: pi  virtualbox-6.0                             6.0.4-128413~Ubuntu~bionic                   amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start and stop VirtualBox guests via command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805662/how-to-start-and-stop-virtualbox-guests-via-command-line). Includes complete instruction on how to determine which VM the system *thinks* is running, and how to easily correct that.

Comment: I have tried all above points. Restarted system several times, removed all the virtualbox and vbox references. No services is running with virtualbox or vbox references but apt says virtualbox is still installed and also gives vbox service running message which is a bit strange and annoying.

Comment: also try sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-dkms